# Writing in an invisible table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'd like to list a few phrases in one language, and their meanings in another language.

I thought about doing it like that:

```
Sentence 1 ---------- Translation 1
Longer Sentence ----- Longer Translation
```

Without the hyphens, of course. The point is that I want to break the page into two parts, and be able to write a line in the first part, then line in the second part, etc., just like an invisible table in Word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for typesetting tables. Here is an example illustrating this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sentence 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Translation 1} \\ \midrule
    Longer Sentence & Longer Translation \\
    This is a very long sentence that spans at least two lines in the table & 
      Hierdie is 'n lang sin wat ten minste twee lyne in die tabel span \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Some specifics about this example:

- The table has evenly spaced column, each of width `0.4\linewidth` (40% of the line width) and is set it `p`aragraph style;
- `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` was used to override the default `p`aragraph style formatting of the columns in the headings; and
- `booktabs` provides `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` to highlight the header, separation from the table body and the bottom of the table.

Other formatting options are also possible, including thicker horizontal rules, or coloured tables.

Answer (score 10):

What requires special attention in Word, is quite easy in LaTeX:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Sentence 1 & Translation 1 \\
Longer Sentence & Longer Translation \\
...
\end{tabular}
```

won't create any rule around cells. Rules between rows can be used for separating visually different sections of the table, they are produced with `\hline` or with the `...rule` commands provided by **booktabs**.

Vertical rules in a table are discouraged in good typography.

Comment: I don't understand why the other answer was chosen as solution, when this is the answer, which truly creates an _invisible_ table. This is the real solution to the question.

Comment: If someone else stumbles upon this solution and finds the following error when compiling:
"! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{tabular}{11}" - note that the "ll" is not the number "11" for your font size, it is two separate letters (lowercase 'LL') that should probably be separated by a whitespace for clarification. More on the meaning of those options can be found here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables