# How to describe line of equation instead of autonumbering

Tags: align

Currently, I am using the \align method in this way:

```
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}(Z \leq z) &= \mathcal{P}t\{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
& = \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
& = F_1 * F_2
\end{align}
```

(sample code was found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105635/align-multiline-equation-with-expression-after-equal-sign))

This produces the following results (including an automatic equation line numbering system):
[image]

Would it be possible to replace those autonumbers with a description added in manually? I already know there is a way to remove the autonumbers, but I also would like to add some text to describe each line. Is this possible or too difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\tag*{<stuff>}` to add descriptions without the surrounding `(`...`)` common to tags. If you want custom tags surrounded by `(`...`)`, use `\tag{<stuff>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{P}(Z \leq z) &= \mathcal{P} t \{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta) \} \tag{description1}                   \\
                        &= \exp(mt) \star \left\{ \frac{\ell}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-\ell^2/{4t}) \right\} \\
                        &= F_1 \times F_2 \tag{description2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It's probably better to use a macro-like approach through something like

```
\newcommand{\eqdesc}[2][2em]{\tag*{#2}\hspace{#1}}
```

which inserts a `2em` space at the end of the `\tag*`, effectively indenting it from the right-margin. This could separate it visually from other, regular `\tag`s, if needed.

A more `tabular`-like display of descriptions is possible if you just add another equation into the mix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{P}(Z \leq z) &= \mathcal{P} t \{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta) \} &
    \text{description1} \\
                        &= \exp(mt) \star \left\{ \frac{\ell}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-\ell^2/{4t}) \right\} \\
                        &= F_1 \times F_2 &
    \text{description2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

There will be a visible space between the equations to separate them.

Comment: Hmm... is there any way to put it a little closer to the left instead of having it right-aligned to the entire page? It's a little nit-picky but it just looks kinda odd...

Comment: @Daneolog: Yes. `\tag` and `\tag*` are similar to equation numbering. In fact, if you use add a `\label`, you can `\ref` it later. If you're not using any `\label`-`\ref`s with these descriptions, you can manhandle them slightly using something like `\newcommand{\eqdesc}[2][2em]{\tag*{#2\hspace{#1}}}`. This puts a `\tag*` with a default space of `2em` on the right, effectively pushing it in `2em` from the right margin. Use `\eqdesc[3em]{stuff}` to change the default spacing. Is this more in line with what you're after?

Comment: Hmm somewhat.  I guess what I was technically going for was a more tabular format, similar to what `\begin{tabular}` does [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36476/180204)

Comment: This makes it look like the description is still left-oriented while on the right side of the equations.

Comment: @Daneolog: You can add another equation as your "description", encapsulating it inside `\text`. I've added that as another option to my answer.

Comment: Perfect!  Works like a charm :)  Thanks so much